# SQLite queries not doing anything

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm trying to use a sqlite database with my javafx application but when I do anything with it nothing happens on the database and I get no error...

Main:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    Main.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    primaryStage.setTitle("Welcome to ServerDashboard");
    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
        event.consume();
        onClose();
    });

    MainConfig.load();
    DatabaseController.createNewDatabase("data.db");

    MainMenu.show(primaryStage);
}
```

Database controller :

```
public class DatabaseController {
public static void createNewDatabase(String fileName) {

    String url = "jdbc:sqlite:" + fileName;

    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS warehouses (\n"
            + " id integer PRIMARY KEY,\n"
            + " name text NOT NULL,\n"
            + " capacity real\n"
            + ");";

    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url)) {
        if (conn != null) {
            DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
            System.out.println("The driver name is " + meta.getDriverName());
            System.out.println("The file was created in : " + new File("").getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + fileName);
            System.out.println("A new database has been created.");

            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute(sql);

            System.out.println("A new table has been created");

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}
Output :

```
The driver name is SQLite JDBC
The file was created in : N:\Code\Minecraft Java\ServerDashboard\data.db
A new database has been created.
A new table has been created
```

I tried every tutorial I could find but none seems to work...

Comment: I don't think you want the "\n"s in the sql.  [From *the* tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html): String query = "select COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, SALES, TOTAL from COFFEES";

Comment: @mcalex I tried without too it doesnt work either

Comment: Maybe try a directory with no spaces (ie not "Minecraft Java").  It looks like you pass in a relative `fileName`, try passing the absolute reference.  What does happen?  Is the db file modified at all?  Is there an existing warehouses table?  Try to show what diagnostic info you've uncovered.

Answer (score 0):

I have a little project that make sqlite connections maybe it can help you find your bug. If not try to debug your script isolating the query statement. It always helps.

https://github.com/saaimons/Java/tree/master/pyMultas_SQLite3

Good luck